# Bootstrap component does not want to render in Datatables function

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-5

```
var dt_filter = dt_filter_table.DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '/banner/data',
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    console.error('DataTables AJAX error:', error);
                    console.log('XHR response:', xhr.responseText);
                }
            },
            // columns: [
            //     { data: 'title' },
            //     { data: 'doctor_id' },
            //     { data: 'create_date' },
            //     { data: 'updated_at' },
            //     { data: 'actions' }
            // ],
            aoColumns: [
                { "data": "title" },
                { "data": "created_at" },
                { "data": 'updated_at' },
                {
                    "mData": "id",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (data) {
                            return '<div class="col-sm-6 p-4"><input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" /><span class="switch-toggle-slider"><span class="switch-on" ></span><span class="switch-off"></span></span></div>'
                        }

                    }
                },
                {
                    "mData": "id",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'><a class='btn btn-primary me-2' href='banner/detail/" + data + "'>Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger mr-2 text-white' onclick='deleteConfirm(" + data + ")'>Delete</a></div>";
                    }
                }
            ],
            orderCellsTop: true,
            dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"l><"col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end"f>><"table-responsive"t><"row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>>'
        });
```

i have this code for rendering datatable with laravel php. i have a problems when i want to render switch component in second last object in aoColumn property. it always says that the checkbox is always null, my current assu,ption is there is a problem between datatable and bootstrap.
how do i solve this problem?

Comment: between database and bootstrap is the entirety  your application. have you checked the network response for that checkbox and tried to change it ?